# MySQL Replication - Master Position Not Changing

Tags: mysql, position, replication

The position of my Master is not updating and I've gone through every other replication-issue post that I could find ... still no luck. Here's what I've got:

Master /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 1
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/binary.log
binlog_do_db = securityDB
```

Slave /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 2 
master-host = 192.168.1.130
master-port = 3306
master-user = slave
master-password = slave
replicate-do-db = securityDB
```

The processlist on the master shows that the slave is connected:

```
    *************************** 4. row ***************************
         Id: 86
       User: root
       Host: localhost:59948
         db: securitydb
    Command: Sleep
       Time: 350
      State: 
       Info: NULL
    *************************** 5. row ***************************
         Id: 138
       User: root
       Host: localhost
         db: securitydb
    Command: Query
       Time: 0
      State: NULL
       Info: show processlist
    *************************** 6. row ***************************
         Id: 187
       User: slave
       Host: macbookpro17:59477
         db: NULL
    Command: Binlog Dump
       Time: 600
      State: Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated
       Info: NULL

The slave process list shows that it's connected to the master:
*************************** 5. row ***************************
     Id: 532
   User: root
   Host: localhost
     db: securitydb
Command: Sleep
   Time: 689
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 6. row ***************************
     Id: 922
   User: system user
   Host: 
     db: NULL
Command: Connect
   Time: 715
  State: Waiting for master to send event
   Info: NULL
*************************** 7. row ***************************
     Id: 923
   User: system user
   Host: 
     db: NULL
Command: Connect
   Time: 714
  State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
   Info: NULL
```

Master variables like '%bin%':

```
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size                       | 32768                |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF                  |
| binlog_format                           | STATEMENT            |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                  | 32768                |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF                  |
| log_bin                                 | ON                   |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators         | OFF                  |
| max_binlog_cache_size                   | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                         | 1073741824           |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size              | 18446744073709547520 |
| sql_log_bin                             | ON                   |
| sync_binlog                             | 0                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Slave variables like '%bin%':

```
 +-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
    | Variable_name                           | Value                          |
    +-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
    | bind_address                            | *                              |
    | binlog_cache_size                       | 32768                          |
    | binlog_checksum                         | CRC32                          |
    | binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF                            |
    | binlog_format                           | STATEMENT                      |
    | binlog_max_flush_queue_time             | 0                              |
    | binlog_order_commits                    | ON                             |
    | binlog_row_image                        | FULL                           |
    | binlog_rows_query_log_events            | OFF                            |
    | binlog_stmt_cache_size                  | 32768                          |
    | innodb_api_enable_binlog                | OFF                            |
    | innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF                            |
    | log_bin                                 | ON                             |
    | log_bin_basename                        | /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin       |
    | log_bin_index                           | /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index |
    | log_bin_trust_function_creators         | OFF                            |
    | log_bin_use_v1_row_events               | OFF                            |
    | max_binlog_cache_size                   | 18446744073709547520           |
    | max_binlog_size                         | 1073741824                     |
    | max_binlog_stmt_cache_size              | 18446744073709547520           |
    | sql_log_bin                             | ON                             |
    | sync_binlog                             | 0                              |
    +-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

But the master position isn't moving and replcation is stuck. I've noticed that the database is showing in all lower-case letters in the process list but I've changed the replicate_do_db to all lowercase and it doesn't help. The database name is actually securityDB. I've tried master reset, slave reset, creating new bin logs ... nothing is getting me there. I'm sure it's something simple ...

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a question for [so]. [dba.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: create a replication user account and give proper rights.

Comment: As it turned out, the database name was converted to lower case on startup so replication needed to be configured using lower case.

Answer (score -1):

You need to restart the mysql server after changing the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file.

The command is :

```
service mysqld restart
```